# Browserify the node.js http server

Tags: node.js, http, browserify

We created a simple js file, intending to find out if http.createServer works on client browser or not:

```
var http = require("http")
var server = http.createServer()
server.listen(9024, function () {
    console.log("demo server listening on port 9024")
})
```

and embedded it into a html after browserify.

Display the html in chrome, unfortunately, it always fails on line 2 on http.createServer():

```
"Uncaught Type Error: undefined is not a function"
```

We also played around with "serve-browserify" a bit without success.

We have attempted the same thing on both chrome and firefox, and on Linux and Windows. All failed.
Searching through the web, there are quite a few examples for browserify http into the browser.
They all appear to be simple invocation of browserify. However we don't seem to be able to get the same good result.
Your help will be greately appreciated.

Comment: Sorry, I've been struggling with formatting the question for submitting. Actually the error is on "var server = http.createServer()", line 2

Comment: To be precise, the error "Uncaught Type Error: ..." was issued against line 2 of the original node.js code.

Answer (score 3):

You can't use Node.js modules in the browser. All Browserify does is bundling CommonJS modules, it does not allow you to run server side code in the browser.

Comment: @BenFortune `http-browserify` is just a clone of a subset of `http`'s API, not really the same module.

Comment: Not sure if I understand this. "A subset of http's API" but not really the same module, and with unknown functionality?? So what is the purpose of providing that in the builtins?

Comment: We actually have the logic for running as a TCP server inside a Chrome web extension, which is too low level. I guess we'd like to have a higher level server (http server) so the request/response can be packaged up nicely in a class. We need to examine the header and manipulate it. Unfortunately http-parser-js is still in early development.

Comment: You are getting the error because you do the wrong thing; you just don't have access to sockets in (Browser) JavaScript. Aside from non-standard environments that provide them (Node, Chrome extensions etc).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I understand what you say. Still just kind of wondering why http.createServer is provided by browserify in the first place.

Comment: Is it? When I run your code, I get `TypeError: http.createServer is not a function`

Comment: Went back to look at the documentation on 
"http-browserify", which is bundled in with browserify. It appears to be a very small subset of the original http class. I probably not gonna be able to do the original full http things.