# Use Node's http module fully in Browserify

Tags: javascript, node.js, browserify

I want to run following Node.js code in ordinary browser such as Chrome:

```
var http = require('http')
var assert = require('assert')
http.createServer((req, res) => {
    // Send hello greetings for all clients.
    res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'text/html' })
    res.end('<h1>Hello, world!</h1>')
}).listen(3000, () => {
    // Get the response myself.
    http.request({
        hostname: 'localhost',
        port: 3000,
        path: '/',
        method: 'GET'
    }, res => {
        assert.equals(res.statusCode, 200)
        // Get the chunked content of the response.
        res.setEncoding('utf8')
        var content = ''
        res.on('data', (chunk) => {
            content += chunk
        })
        res.on('end', () => {
            // Finish to get the chunked.
            assert.equals(content, '<h1>Hello, world!</h1>')
        })
    })
})
```

When the code runs on the browser correctly, two assertions are passed without any errors.

It needs browser-compatible `require(...)` function for running Node code in browser.
I find a suitable library what is [Browserify](http://browserify.org/), but there are [not fully-implemented `http` module](https://github.com/substack/http-browserify) of Node.js.

So unfortunately, I cannot use `http.createServer(...)` and `http.listen(...)`  function.

How can I run the Node code correctly on the browser?

**Addition**:
It doesn't require that `http.createServer(...)` did **NOT** host new server, just simulate. `http.request(...)` and `http.listen(...)` are same.

I think that can simulate using mock object.

Comment: Might be a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24735593/browserify-the-node-js-http-server

Comment: @Sargo Darya I see. I add some addition in the question.